# Why is my Reactive Cocoa not being called to check textfield for changes?

Tags: binding, reactive-cocoa

Im new to RCA.  I found this tut online [ReactiveCocoaSamurai](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2013/03/basic-mvvm-with-reactivecocoa.html)

Its pretty simple...In the original project they separate the model from the view controller, as they should :)  But when I try to do it, I can't bind (or connect) the view controller property to the model property.

Everything is set up correctly because if I put all the code in the view controller class, it WORKS! 
The reason why it works is because I don't need the line of code in the view controller that binds the model to the view controller properties.

But when I try to split it up as the tutorial has it, I get an error at that line.

This works when in the view controller:

The Signal method

```
-(RACSignal *)forbiddenNameSignal {
    return [RACObserve(self, username) filter:^BOOL(NSString *newName) {
        return [self.forbiddenNames containsObject:newName]; //This yields a YES BOOLEAN?
    }];
}
```

This goes in the viewDidLoad of the viewController:

```
[[self.usernameField.rac_textSignal distinctUntilChanged] subscribeNext:^(NSString *x) {self.username = x;}];

 [self.mymodel.forbiddenNameSignal subscribeNext:^(NSString *name) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Forbidden Name!"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The name %@ has been forbidden!",name]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            self.mymodel.username = @"";
 }];
```

Of course the UITextField is in storyboards and hooked up and the forbidden array is defined in viewDidLoad as well.

This doesn't work:

LoginModel.m

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(!self) return nil;
    //forbidden names array
    self.forbiddenNames = @[ @"Peter",@"Piper",@"Picker"];
    return self;
}


-(RACSignal *)forbiddenNameSignal {
    return [RACObserve(self, username) filter:^BOOL(NSString *newName) {
        return [self.forbiddenNames containsObject:newName]; //This yields a YES BOOLEAN?
    }];
}
```

ViewController.m viewDidLoad:

```
self.mymodel = [LoginModel new];
RAC(self.usernameField.text) = [RACAbleWithStart(self.mymodel.username) distinctUntilChanged];
[[self.usernameField.rac_textSignal distinctUntilChanged] subscribeNext:^(NSString *x) {
            self.username = x;
        }];
[self.mymodel.forbiddenNameSignal subscribeNext:^(NSString *name) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Forbidden Name!"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The name %@ has been forbidden!",name]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            self.mymodel.username = @"";
        }];
```

I get an error at the RAC line saying expected identifier & warning of "signalWithStarting..." deprecated for "valuesForKeyPath".

What I have tried:

```
RAC(self, usernameField) = [RACObserve(self, mymodel.username) distinctUntilChanged];
```

and ...

```
RAC(self, usernameField) = RAC(self, mymodel.username);
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Or about why indenting code is not working either :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your problem, but there are a few things that don't look right in your code.

Firstly, treat tutorials regarding ReactiveCocoa on the web with caution! When ReactiveCocoa 2.0 came out a few months ago there were a lot of breaking API changes. The RACAbleWithStart macro you have been trying to use [is deprecated](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#simplified-and-safer-kvo).

Also, this code looks wrong to me:

```
[[self.usernameField.rac_textSignal distinctUntilChanged]
    subscribeNext:^(NSString *x) {self.username = x;}];
```

This is taking the `rac_textSignal` and assigning the next event value to the `username` property. Firstly, I am pretty sure `distinctUntilChanged` is not required here, the signal will only emit events when the text field changes. Secondly, to assign the a signal to a property you can simply use the RAC macro:

```
RAC(self, username) = self.usernameField.rac_textSignal;
```

I see that the root of your problem is that you are trying to bind a property on your `LoginModel` to a property in your view controller. ReactiveCocoa has the `RACChannelTo` macro which is specifically for this purpose, however I have never used it, and have an idea that will side-step it!

In my opinion your LoginModel should become a view model, and it should expose a `username` in order that it models the view (because that is what view models do!). You can then bind this within your view controller like so:

```
RAC(self.loginViewModel, username) = self.usernameField.rac_textSignal;
```

You then have to turn the `username` property change into a signal within your view model, so that you can use your filter ... so within your LoginViewModel initialization code ...

```
[[RACObserve(self, username)
  filter:^BOOL(NSString *username) {
    return [self.forbiddenNames containsObject:username]; 
  }
  subscribeNext:^BOOL(NSString *forbiddenName) {
    // do your thang!
  }];
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thx!  I got the binding to work with the RAC macro.  I also eliminated the distinctUntilChanged so the natural question now is, what does distinctUntilChanged do different than just subscribeNext? Finally, your RACObserve filter: subscribeNext: is doing in one shot what my code split up (filter in the model and subscribeNext in the vc...any thoughts on that?

Comment: @marciokoko **distinctUntilChanged** 'filters' values that not equals to the previous one. `self.viewModel.name = @"foo";self.viewModel.name = @"foo";`triggers only the first call.

Comment: I want to display alert in "subscribeNext". So how can I display alert in view from view model?